# setFetchMode to type Class using namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to populate some variables in a PHP class by using setFetchMode and FETCH_CLASS.

```
<?php # index.php
use myproject\user\User;
use myproject\page\Page;

$q = 'SELECT * FROM t';
$r = $pdo->query($q);

  // Set the fetch mode:
  $r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Page');

 // Records will be fetched in the view:
 include('views/index.html');
?>
```

In my view file, I have:

```
<?php # index.html
// Fetch the results and display them:
while ($page = $r->fetch()) {
echo "<article>
<h1><span>{$page->getDateAdded()}</span>{$page->getTitle()}</h1>
<p>{$page->getIntro()}</p>
<p><a href=\"page.php?id={$page->getId()}\">read more here...</a></p>
</article>
";
}
?>
```

These methods are from Class: Page.php:

```
<?php # Page.php
function getCreatorId() {
 return $this->creatorId;
}
function getTitle() {
 return $this->title;
}
function getContent() {
 return $this->content;
}
function getDateAdded() {
 return $this->dateAdded;
}
?>
```

It's pretty straightforward when using standard classes, that is, I've had it all working fine; name-spaces seem problematic however.

For example if I use:

```
<?php # index.php
require('Page.php'); // Page class
$r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Page'); // works
?>
```

But when using namespaces,

```
<?php # index.php
use myproject\page\Page;
?>
// Set the fetch mode:
$r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Page'); // problem

// Records will be fetched in the view:
include('views/index.html');
?>
```

Browse to index.php and the browser reports:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getDateAdded() on a non-object in /var/www/PHP/firstEclipse/views/index.html on line 5

My namespace paths are all set-up correctly, as I've successfully instantiated objects using the above naming conventions, for example:

```
<?php # index.php

use myproject\page\User; # class: /myproject/page/user/User.php
$b = new User();
print $b->foo(); // hello
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### If you are using PHP earlier than 5.5

You need to provide the fully qualified name of the class:

```
use myproject\page\Page;

$r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'myproject\page\Page');
```

It's unfortunate that you have to repeat yourself like this (this code would break if you decided to switch to a different class `Page` from another namespace), but there is no way around the ugliness.

#### If you are using PHP 5.5

You are in luck! The new [`::class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) keyword was designed to help with exactly this problem:

```
// PHP 5.5+ code!
use myproject\page\Page;

// Page::class evaluates to the fully qualified name of the class
// because PHP is providing a helping hand
$r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Page::class);
```

Comment: Wish I could upgrade to PHP 5.5... :-)

Comment: I can't get any of these methods to work. The first thing I tried was 'myproject\page\Page' but this doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any way I can acheive something similar using Mysqli rather than PDO?

Comment: @AndrewCookson: I 'm not sure if that will make a difference, but what about adding another slash in front? `\myproject\...`. For mysqli, [`fetch_object`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) has an argument that allows you to specify the class.

Comment: @Jon, the leading slash has no effect, with the script reporting: Fatal error: Call to a member function getDateAdded() on a non-object. I'll look into fetch_object. It's a shame that PDO doesn't work though.